# How to get google Authorization Code using POSTMAN

Tags: api, postman

I want to get the **Authorization code** to generate **ACCESS TOKEN** and **REFRESH TOKEN** for my Application. I'm trying to get the job done using **POSTMAN**. But this seems not working. I'm attaching a screenshot of **POSTMAN**. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?
Any useful suggestion or alternative solution is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I figured it out myself. To Generate the Refresh token and access token the first time, I needed Authorization Code. I thought I need to generate it again and again but it Turns out I needed it only once and when I got the access_token and refresh_token, I can easily generate access_token by using refresh_token.
Here's the corrected API request flow-

### Requesting Authorization code

Using Web
[image: POSTMAN REQUESTION PREVIEW]

### Requesting ACCESS TOKEN and REFRESH TOKEN

[image: POSTMAN ACCESS TOKEN AND REFRESH PREVIEW]

### Regenerating Access Token using refresh token

[image: POSTMAN ACCESS TOKEN GENERATION PREVIEW]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postman.com/praveendvd-public/workspace/postman-tricks-and-tips/documentation/8296678-5dc51f3f-c7b0-4c66-a457-11af32bb1a63?entity=request-6dda15f2-306b-4915-a585-

use this public collection as an example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to do this using settings within the Postman GUI. There is an Authorization tab in which you can specify auth type, configure new tokens, add your client id & secret, etc.